# How do you update a running docker image on digital ocean droplet?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, droplet

I have a docker image running on port 3000 on my droplet on digital ocean.

I did some updates and created a new image and pushed it to my github packages.

I thought when I push the new image that the old one would just get overriden but Im getting an error saying

**"Bind for 0.0.0.0:3000 failed: port is already allocated".**

I run the following command when I get the above:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 docker.pkg.github.com/UserName/Project/newImageName:1
```

This made me think that I could remove the old image and add the new one but that does not seem ideal but I have not found a command that can override/update to a new one.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: When you run an image, an instance is created, which is as a container. Updating an image doesn't affect the container itself.

Comment: Is there a way to update the container? Just wondering if I can update this in a way without deleting the current container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the image using `--rm` parameter (which removes the container upon exit).

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 docker.pkg.github.com/UserName/Project/newImageName:1
```

After exiting (stopping the container) you can `docker pull` to get the latest version of the image and then re-run